# API/WMI Query for complete list of hotfixes and updates installed on a system?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, windows-update, hotfix

Previously, how to query for a list of hotfixes installed on a Windows system has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627551/wmi-query-for-list-of-hotfixes-installed-in-a-system), and the use of WMI and the class `Win32_QuickFixEngineering` was suggested as providing the information. However [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that from Vista onwards this particular class only returns hotfixes, and not updates installed by other means.

[An older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes) discusses the use of this class to get installed updates indicating the author is also not satisfied using it because of the limitation I described above. Unfortunately, as a comment on the accepted answer points out, the alternative solution of using the Windows Update Agent API will still indicate a hotfix has been installed even after it has been subsequently removed (it's querying the installation history, not the currently installed updates).

Does anybody know how to get in C# (via WMI or some other API) a complete list of updates and hotfixes installed on the system, which doesn't exclude some means by which updates may be installed, and won't return updates that were subsequently removed? Essentially, I'm after the same set of data as is available in 'Programs and Features' under the 'View Installed Updates' pane.

Apologies if this discussion ought to have been had on either of the linked questions previously looking at this issue, however with my current reputation the only way I could contribute to either question would be to submit a new answer, and that's definitely not the right way to ask a further question such as this.

Thanks!

Comment: try systeminfo.exe at comand line.

Comment: Since you brought up `systeminfo.exe`, `wmic qfe get Hotfixid` is an easier way to get the information from console, or `wmic qfe` gives a more complete summary. However, I would like to be able to access this information programmatically. In the absence of a more complete registry or API based list, I may resort to parsing the output from the terminal.

Comment: This help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes

Comment: Thanks, but you ought to note that's the third link in my question above, the problems with the methods discussed there are highlighted on the original question and in my summary.

Comment: I have tried using [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in C++ to retrieve updates installed. WUA API is helpful to retrieve the data through programming. I think it should be supported in C# as well, but I have never tried in C#. How ever still I am also trying to find the best way between WMIC QFE GET and WUA API. If you have any info Please add your comments.

Comment: I'm not sure if the WUA API retrieves all types of hotfix, or if it is only those installed by windows update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a reliable and complete programmatic way to achieve this I ended up using the `wmic qfe` command.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know anything that is installed and able to be uninstalled must be registered in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`  It appears that subkey names KB999999 are reserved for system updates (hotfixes or service packs).  Something that is an update will have a REG_SZ value within that subkey named ParentKeyName which links to the registry entry that it updated.

For example, I have Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008, so, I have a subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\KB968369` in the registry.  It has a REG_SZ value named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\KB968369\ParentKeyName` with the value "Microsoft SQL Server 10 Release".  Because I have SQL Server 2008 installed (as KB968369 is the SP for it) I also have a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft SQL Server 10 Release` which is the ParentKeyName link.

You can tell what type an update is from the ReleaseType REG_SZ value. For example, the KB968369 install has a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\KB968369\ReleaseType` value of "ServicePack"

I assume only the updates that can be uninstalled are registered under the `Uninstall` key.  There is also the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Patches` registry key (referenced in various places like here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971187 ) that seems to detail various system updates.

there's also apparently a Microsoft Update object that you can instantiate and query.  An example of this is detailed here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/athif/archive/2005/11/20/76035.aspx

I'm not sure if that gives you entirely what you want; but it's some various things I've learned over the years...

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful collection of info although unfortunately neither of those registry keys actually contain a reference to the specific Hotfix I'm testing with on my fresh Win7 install. Looking at another machine with much more stuff installed I can see info related to various Hotfixes and updates so it seems some info is stored there.